Why do recompile attempts fail with Makefile?
When attempting to recompile an app that is currently running on Redhat 7.9 to new platform running AlmaLinux 8 the following error occurs:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [pest.mak:307: pest] Error 1

But Fortran, GCC, and G++ are installed as shown here:
[XXX@ip-0A000006 ~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-16)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[XXX@ip-0A000006 ~]$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
[XXX@ip-0A000006 ~]$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-16)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[XXX@ip-0A000006 ~]$ which gfortran
/usr/bin/gfortran
[XXX@ip-0A000006 ~]$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
[XXX@ip-0A000006 ~]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-16)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I appreciate any insights you folks can offer.

You probably need a dev package to get you libgfortran.so or the moral equivalent.  I'm a gentoo guy though, so I can't help with the specific package you'll need.

Did you try to install the ligfortran package?

Although I'm sure that the comments are correct and you're missing some package (only people familiar with AlmaLinux will be able to tell you but you should be able to find it yourself with searching), in general when asking questions please include the command line that caused the error, not just the error message.  In this case it would be the linker command that make invoked so we could see the arguments that were provided to the link command.

gfortran installations generally include libgfortran, either directly or as a dependency, because gfortran is largely useless without it.  It looks like Alma takes the dependency approach.  But the library is not necessarily installed with a name or in a location that facilitates linking it explicitly, which it appears your build is trying to do.  Alma does not appear to have a corresponding development package, which is not that surprising, so you may just need to figure out where libgfortran.so is installed, and add an appropriate -L option to your build.

Renaud - it was installed.  ]# dnf install ligfortran
Last metadata expiration check: 2:40:22 ago on Thu 29 Aug 2024 05:32:13 PM UTC.
No match for argument: ligfortran
Error: Unable to find a match: ligfortran
[root@ip-0A000006 ~]# dnf install libgfortran
Last metadata expiration check: 2:40:35 ago on Thu 29 Aug 2024 05:32:13 PM UTC.
Package libgfortran-8.5.0-16.el8_7.alma.x86_64 is already installed.

find / -name libgfortran.so
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/197263723dd411f6b6e052f68e41bd6ac5947b1a114c0ef7915663ac7b6bf17a/diff/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libgfortran.so
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/32/libgfortran.so
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/libgfortran.so            # echo $PATH
/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/:/opt/cycle/jetpack/bin:/root/bin

John - not sure what I need to do with the -L option.

I don't know if this is helpful but here are the parameters specified in the .mak   DEFINES= -DUNIX -DFLUSHFILE -DSLEEP;
F90=gfortran;
LD=gfortran;
FFLAGS=-c -O3 -static;
LDFLAGS=-static;
